# How to click a random link in a web element

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am currently training in Selenium. The objective of the task is to:

1. Navigate to a random Wikipedia page
2. Pick a random category from the page's list of categories
3. Select a random article from the list of pages in the selected category
4. Output the compared differences between the categories of the original random page and the second one.

I have gotten all the way to the category page, but for some reason the code wont click on a random article within that page.

Here is my current code for the category page

```
        //Navigating to the category list at the bottom of the page
        WebElement Category = driver.findElement(By.id("mw-normal-catlinks"));
        Category.click();
        //finds a random link in the category list
        Random r = new java.util.Random();
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'mw-category']"));    
        //picks a random link
        WebElement randomElement = links.get(r.nextInt(links.size()));
        randomElement.click();

        WebElement newCategory = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class= 'mw-category-generated']//div[@class= 'mw-category']"));
        newCategory.click();
        Random n = new java.util.Random();
        List<WebElement> ArticleLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class= 'mw-category-generated']//div[@class= 'mw-category']"));
        WebElement randomElement2 = articleLinks.get(n.nextInt(articleLinks.size()));
        randomElement2.click();
```

Comment: It's nice that you have goals and requirements, but is there a question here?

Comment: I would suggest that "click"ing isn't the answer, you can use the GET method and navigate the URL: [FOREXAMPLE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dumbass#Synonyms)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson No real question. Just to get through those steps. I guess my personal question is what am I doing wrong? Why won't the program click the random articles?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems good. I'm not sure why it's not working. Probably you are locating the random elements by randomElement and randomElement2 but you are clicking the elements. Please add below lines of code then it will work.
randomElement.click()
randomElement2.click()

Comment: I have added the following code above. But, it still doesnt work.

Comment: I believe the code clicking the category link and stopping there. Please let me know what is the intention for the below line of code
`List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("mw-pages"));`
as I am not able to identify any element in the category page with the tag name "mw-pages"

Comment: That line of code is supposed to locate the list inside the web element specified. I assumed that the tagName wasnt specific enough and changed it to an xpath...still nothing has happened.

Comment: Seems your locators are not working. It's not code issue. Work on the locators by some tools like firebug

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems I see here:

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("mw-pages"));
```

Are you sure that the actual links are by tag `mw-pages`?  If you're not sure, take a look at the HTML.  Does it show:

```
<mw-pages></mw-pages>
```

If not, then you're probably looking for a class or an ID. In which case, you need to use those selector strategies.

The other problem:

```
By.tagName("//div[@class= 'mw-category-generated']//div[@class= 'mw-category']")
```

The string you specified is not a tag name.  Again, as mentioned above, `By.tagName` is looking for `<tag-name>`.  This selector strategy is clearly an XPath, so use

```
By.xpath("//div[@class= 'mw-category-generated']//div[@class= 'mw-category']")
```

*Additionally*, drop the habit of PascalCasing your objects.  Java is camelCased, not PascalCased.  It's not relevant to your issue, but I think it's worth advising.

```
WebElement category; // not WebElement Category;
List<WebElement> articleLinks; // not List<WebElement> ArticleLinks;
```

Comment: I have updated the original post to match your changes. However, I still cannot get it to click a random link within the list of articles.